# Routes in the address bar

Tags: angularjs

I am using the $routeProvider to configure my routes:

```
.when('/Caseload', {
    controller: 'CaseloadController',
    templateUrl: '/template/caseload/caseload.tmpl.html',
    resolve: {
        caseload: ['CaseloadService', function(CaseloadService){
            return CaseloadService.getCaseload();
        }]
    }
})
```

And my link looks like this:

```
<div class="tab"><a href="/Caseload">Caseload</a></div>
```

When I navigate to http://localhost:1234 and then click the link the url in the address bar now looks like http://localhost:1234/Caseload.

**EDIT**
To clarify what I am asking, if you check the ng-view docs they have a book example where you click the link for a book and the view is updated with info about the location.

When you click one of those links however the address bar of the browser DOES NOT change.

Before I click the link the address bar says:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

After I click one of the book links it still says:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView in the address bar.

When I click the links in my page the address bar DOES change; it updates the address to be my route.

So before I click the link pointing to /Caseload my address bar says:

http://localhost:1234

After clicking the link it says:

http://localhost:1234/Caseload

This is not a valid url but a route in my app. What do I need to do to have the $routeProvider NOT put my routes in the address bar?

Comment: Read this to understand all the nuances with route URLs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes

Comment: I'm using html5 mode.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what I am asking. When I click an anchor in my page it updates the view but it also updates the address bar. I don't want this to happen and am not sure why it is happening. If you look at the ng-view docs they have a Book example. When I click the various tabs in the example the view is updated but the address bar is not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you misunderstand how the documentation works.  the URL is definitely changing, but because those examples are running in an iframe, you don't see the change in the address bar of the documentation page.  see the example running in it's own view at http://run.plnkr.co/y48XXw2PrPa105qR/

Comment: The part I was missing is that in both the ng-view page AND the plunker they link to, the code is running in an iframe. When I view your link running in its own view it acts just like my app. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your link like that:

```
<a href="#/Caseload">Caseload</a>
```

The key is hash `#`.